# Google drive api upload & display with JWT authentication

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, google-drive-api

I want to upload files into my google drive account with Node.JS but while uploading the files I want to create a folder for these files and give a specific access to some emails to view them into my google drive account , the basic scenario is i have a form which i upload for example 3 files (video,pdf,image) , then i made a multiselect input field that put 3 emails inside then i click upload , i want only these 3 emails to display this folder and everyone with other email cannot view the files therefor my login system is JsonWebToken ( JWT ) so is it possible to do this , I just want to upload files to google driver and then my frontend checks who has logged in with JWT token access then display these files in the frontend.

I made this code but i cannot find a way to add a file and then add a permission to this file who can view these files :

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const googleScope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
const googleKey = process.env.GOOGLE_KEY;
const fs = require('fs')
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Multer = require("multer");


const authenticateGoogle = () => {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: __dirname + "/book-375320-56d9bd2b6239.json",
    scopes: googleScope,
  });
  return auth;
};

const multer = Multer({
  storage: Multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, `${__dirname}/fff`);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);
    },
  }),
  limits: {
    fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024,
  },
});

const uploadToGoogleDrive = async (file , auth ) => {
    const fileMetadata = {
      name: file.originalname,
      parents: ["1PLzjikkBXnSpBNi7OZxh3-XhEAIji_94"]
    };
  
    const media = {
      mimeType: file.mimetype,
      body: fs.createReadStream(file.path),
    };
  
    const driveService = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
  
    const response = await driveService.files.create({
      requestBody: fileMetadata,
      media: media,
      fields: "id",
    });
    return response;
};


const deleteFile = (filePath) => {
    fs.unlink(filePath, () => {
      console.log("file deleted");
    });
};

router.post("/uploadGD", multer.single("file") , async (req , res , next ) => {
    try {
      if (!req.file) {
        res.status(400).send("No file uploaded.");
        return;
      }
      const auth = authenticateGoogle();
      const response = await uploadToGoogleDrive(req.file, auth);
      deleteFile(req.file.path);
      res.status(200).json({ response });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
}});

module.exports = router;
```

I expect to upload files with permissions that who can view my files and then get JWT token and if the JWT token has the same email as the permission files he can view it inside the frontend.

Comment: Who is the owner of the folder of `1PLzjikkBX...`? And, you want to share this folder with the emails? And, about `the basic scenario is i have a form which i upload for example 3 files (video,pdf,image) , then i made a multiselect input field that put 3 emails inside then i click upload , i want only these 3 emails to display this folder and everyone with other email cannot view the files`, I cannot understand the relationship between this and your showing script. And also, if when different other emails except for `3 emails` are used, do you want to share the folder with all emails?

Comment: the 1PLz... is a file inside google drive , but i want to create a node js api request that takes files from the frontend and then upload it inside a folder in google drive and give that folder some emails that can access it , also when the user login to my website he gets authenticated by a JWT token that checks if the JWT token login has that email display to him all google drive data that he has access to , is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be using service account authorization.   Which also implies that you have granted your service account access to the folder in question.

This means it will be up to your code to decide who has access.

I would suggest that in your login system you simply add a new claim to the user which your code can use to decide if this person has access.

How you do this is hard to know without understanding more about the Login to system used by your users.

either way this is not something a service account can do so its up to you too implement within your own system.

Comment: I am using a mongodb with JWT token and a cookie token for my website , i tried to send an array of emails to the backend and use it as a permission but it doesn't work at all it doesn't add these emails to the permission list , all i wanted to do is finding a way to give access to some files to some people but not all my users should have access to all files , i am trying to read google api docs but i cannot find a solution for this.

Comment: As I mentioned this is out of scope for the google drive api and service account.  You need to figure out who it is your JWT belongs to as in who is logged in and then test in your code if this is something you want your app to show the files.     Service account just grant your app access to everything.